# Where should the path from main in package.json point to?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, parceljs

The package.json was created with the yarn cli. It fails when I try to build it. If I remove `"main": "src/index.js"` it works. `src/index.js` exists but it's an empty file for now.

Do I need to specify the path to my bundle or why does this throw an error? Changing the path to what is suggested in the error message doesn't work either.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "source": "src/index.html",
  "browserslist": "supports es6-module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel --open chrome",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-rc.0"
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
$ parcel build
 Build failed.

@parcel/namer-default: Target "main" declares an output file path of "src/index.js" which does not match the compiled bundle type "html".

  .../project/package.json:5:11
    4 |   "description": "project",
  > 5 |   "main": "src/index.js",
  >   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Did you mean "src/index.html"?
    6 |   "source": "src/index.html",
    7 |   "scripts": {

   Try changing the file extension of "main" in package.json.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: From what I can tell, parcel see's main as the destination for it's compiled output, so putting it in the same directory as your source doesn't seem correct.   Should it be `"main": "dist/index.html"`

Comment: @Keith that gives me `@parcel/core: Unexpected output file type .html in target "main"`

Answer (score 3):

The `main` field in `package.json` is intended to be used by library developers (e.g. if you are building a package that you intend to publish to npm to be consumed by others). In this context, it specifies the *output* target - i.e. where parcel should put an optimized commonjs javascript bundle. (see [high-level documentation](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/#package.json%23main) and [detailed documentation](https://parceljs.org/features/targets/#library-targets)).

In your case, it seems like you're building an app, not a library, so I would recommend just removing the `main` field entirely, which should resolve the errors you are seeing.