# Matter.js/Parcel SVG animation does not run on Bluehost server

Tags: javascript, html, parceljs, matter.js

I implemented a Matter.js SVG animation into a website, on localhost it runs well with Parcel. When I upload it to Bluehost server with File Manager, the animation does not work. I get the following error message in the console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './scripts/matter.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

This is my package.json:

````
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean:output": "rimraf dist",
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "matter.js",
    "collisions"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-grid-only-css": "^4.1.3",
    "matter-js": "^0.14.2",
    "parcel": "^2.2.1",
    "poly-decomp": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```


And the imports in my index.js file:


```
import PolyDecomp from "./scripts/poly-decomp.js";
import Matter from "./scripts/matter.js";
```

Thank you in avance, if you can help!
````

Comment: This might be a bit of an onion-peeling exercise, but to start, you probably want to remove the `"main": "index.js"` line from your package.json, unless you're building a library (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544148/4739687)). Also, how did "matter.js" end up in your "scripts" folder? Since it's listed as a dependency in your package.json, I would expect you to be able to reference it directly (e.g. `import Matter from "matter-js"`, or possibly `import * as Matter from "matter-js"` as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50423673/4739687)

Comment: thank you. I did all that you suggested, moved the matter.js and poly-decomp.js files to to root folder, updated the imports, but now I get this error message:

Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at poly-decomp.js:1:1

Comment: I might not have explained that clearly enough - what I meant was that because you have "matter-js" and "ploly-decomp" are part of your package.json dependencies, `npm`/`yarn` should take care of installing them for you into your `node_modules` folder for you. So you don't need to manually copy them anywhere else in your project, and you can refer to them from JavaScript with a [bare specifier](https://parceljs.org/features/dependency-resolution/#bare-specifiers). I've done that successfully in [this github project](https://github.com/astegmaier/stackoverflow-parcel-matter).